# J2ME access Default media player track running in background

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, audio-player

Is there any way to access track being played in Music player running in background in J2ME?
or at least the path of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't able to access the default media player using Java ME.

Answer (score 0):

Search for APIBridge.jar on google. This jar file allows you to read sms from inbox, use native camera application. So there might be possibility, It allows you to use Native Media Player.

Comment: I downloaded it, but there's no documentation for Eclipse..How to configure it with Eclipse.

Comment: All right I got it working, but it only retrieves call logs, music file locations, use camera not even read SMS from inbox (there was no example, do you have one) and nothing more :(

Comment: ok, I was not sure, that's why I wrote "might" in my answer. kindly read my answer again Akshay.

Comment: I understand what you said, just asking (politely) if you have any code example

Comment: Sorry Akshay, I do not have code regarding Media Player, However the other code like reading Inbox,Contacts, you can find it with that .Jar file

Comment: I needed to read sms from inbox + receive them long time back. I will give it a try again with that api.